# PHP Include: Losing UTF-8 characters on included code

Tags: php

I'm including a menubar through php include and for some reason the menubar doesn't display UTF-8 special characters.

The rest of the page works fine, just not the left navigation.

What could be the reason? I tried adding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

on the included file too but I still can't get the caracters.

I'm testing it here:
http://www.lilianasanmiguel.com.ar/acol1.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you actually save the files in UTF-8 encoding in your editor.

Comment: It was but there was no utf-8 characters on the code though and it got saven on ansi. Adding an // Ñ and saving on UTF-8 fixed it

Comment: If "strange" chars appear after encoding your file : 
Ctrl+A > Ctrl+X > UTF-8 encoding > Ctrl+V

Answer (score 2):

Check if the file you include is uft-8 encoded. In Eclipse you can do so by right-clicking in the file an check under "Properties"

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the standard PHP string functions won't work with UTF-8 - they all assume a fixed with character set.  Check your code and make sure you're using the `mb_*` equivalents instead.